# The third argument of the Root function

Tags: equation-solving, functions, polynomials

Consider the roots of an arbitrary indecomposable polynomial:

```
sol = Solve[x^5 + 2 x + 1 == 0, x]
```

The returned expression is

```
{{x -> Root[1 + 2 #1 + #1^5 &, 1]},
 {x -> Root[1 + 2 #1 + #1^5 &, 2]},
 {x -> Root[1 + 2 #1 + #1^5 &, 3]},
 {x -> Root[1 + 2 #1 + #1^5 &, 4]},
 {x -> Root[1 + 2 #1 + #1^5 &, 5]}}
```

Everything seems OK. But now let us evaluate the expression

```
InputForm[sol]
```

Now the returned expression is

```
{{x -> Root[1 + 2*#1 + #1^5 & , 1, 0]},
 {x -> Root[1 + 2*#1 + #1^5 & , 2, 0]}, 
 {x -> Root[1 + 2*#1 + #1^5 & , 3, 0]},
 {x -> Root[1 + 2*#1 + #1^5 & , 4, 0]}, 
 {x -> Root[1 + 2*#1 + #1^5 & , 5, 0]}}
```

Why has the extra argument `0` appeared ?
Is it a bug, mystery or some extremely smart property ?

I use *Mathematica 9.0.1.0* (*64-bit Windows 7*).

Comment: The same happens in *Mathematica* 8.0.4 (64 bit Windows 7).

Comment: The last argument is undocumented, and reflects the method used to isolate roots, and assign them their ordinal numbers. Changing that number might result in change of numerical approximation of the root object, due to change of ordering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Answer by Andrzej Kozlowski](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2006/May/msg00104.html)

> Yes, there is indeed a third, hidden argument. I think it represents
>   (or at least it used to represent)  what is called "the isolating
>   set" of the algebraic number, that is, a subset of the complex plane
>   in which the root object is the only root of the minimal polynomial.
>   This is necessary in order for the roots of the polynomial to be
>   ordered, so that you can speak of the "first roots", "second root" etc.
>
> Mathematica uses two approaches to root isolation: numerical and
>   exact one. Which one is used depends on the value of the option
>   ExactRootIsolation of Root. One can check that the invisible third
>   argument is different (you can extract it with Part). However, it
>   seems to me that the actual form of the third argument was changed
>   (without my noticing it until today ;-)) in some version of
>   Mathematica between 3 and 5. Mathematica used to return an
>   approximate value of the root with the ExactRootIsolation set to
>   False and the corners of the isolating rectangle in the complex plane
>   with  ExactRootIsolation set to True. However, now it seems just to
>   return 0 and 1, which I find impossible to interpret. I am sure,
>   however, that the same information is still stored somewhere...

Andrzej Kozlowski

**Edit***

Also, @Alexey [found it in the docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Root.html#199960501).

Comment: I noticed that there is an [example](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Root.html)  (the "options" section of "examples" for `Root` function's documentation) in the help of Mathematica that demonstrates the third argument of the `Root`.

Comment: Direct link to the explanation in the Documentation: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Root.html#199960501

Comment: Turned into CW, as I'm just posting other people's results