# Matching Root[...] objects with patterns, unexpected hidden argument

Tags: pattern-matching, syntax, symbolic, expression-manipulation

I needed to write patterns that could distinguish between arbitrary-function and polynomial forms of `Root` objects, for example, ``` Root[{-3 + #1 + #1^E &, 1.2``1}] ``` and `Root[-3 + #1 + #1^5 &, 1]`.

```
MatchQ[Root[{-3 + #1 + #1^E &, 1.2``1}], Root[{_, _Real}]]
(* True *)

MatchQ[Root[-3 + #1 + #1^5 &, 1], Root[_, _Integer]]
(* False *)
```

The last result looks unexpected. An investigation shows that there is a third, invisible and, apparently, undocumented argument `0`:

```
Root[-3 + #1 + #1^5 &, 1] // InputForm
(* Root[-3 + #1 + #1^5 & , 1, 0] *)
```

Once we know this, pattern matching is easy to fix, but still there are some questions:

- What's the purpose of this parameter? Is it documented anywhere?
- Why is it invisible in `StandardForm` and `OutputForm`?
- Are there cases when I might need to explicitly provide an argument for it?

Comment: Some info [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34784/193). Curiously enough, it was asked today :)