# When does Root have a third argument

Tags: equation-solving, functions, polynomials

In Mathematica "11.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 20, 2016)",

```
Root[#^4 + 1 &, 2];
```

actually has three arguments, as can be seen from

```
% // InputForm
(* Root[1 + #1^4 & , 2, 0] *)
```

This is well explained in [34764](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34764/1063).  However,

```
((zj /. (sol[[1]] // N))[[1, 1, 1, 2, 2]]);
```

where `sol` is defined [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134391/1063), has only two arguments.

```
% // InputForm
(* Root[..., 2] *)
```

What criteria does `Root` use to determine the number of its arguments?  Note that both instances of `Root` were generated by `Solve`.

Comment: What if you use `FullForm`?

Comment: @xzczd  The number of arguments does not change.

Comment: Further `Root[]` related fun: if the associated polynomial equations are sufficiently complicated (e.g. `Solve[{x^3 y - x y^3 + x^2 z^3 + y^5 == 1, x^5 - x^2 y^3 + y^2 z == 1, x y^2 + y z^3 + x^2 y^2 + z^2 == -1}, {x, y, z}, Reals]`), `Root[]` takes a more elaborate form, having lists of polynomials as its first argument and a list of (apparent) indices as the second argument.